# Як правильніше вживати?

Tags: переклад, словосполучення

"Сукня трапецієподібного силуету" чи "сукня трапецієвидного силуету"?
[image]

В словнику вказано, що це одне і теж. Обидва словосполучення можна використовувати?
"Свободный трапециевидный крой"
"Вільний трапецієподібний крій"?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання містило контекст. Окрім того, запитання, які не демонструють спроби автора самостійно відповісти на запитання, не заохочують інших до того, щоб надавати відповіді.
Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також
[«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).
Ви завжди можете виправити запитання, для цього натисніть [edit].

Answer (score -1):

Згідно до СУМу можна вижати як "[трапецієподібний](http://sum.in.ua/s/trapecijepodibnyj)" так і "[трапецієвидний](http://sum.in.ua/s/trapecijevydnyj)", так як значення в цих слів однакове: "Схожий на трапецію; який має форму трапеції".

Comment: Мені здається, що в запитанні вже містяться ваші дані, можливо варто провести більше дослідження.